# Mongodb query Dates returning as String of numbers

Tags: datetime, mongoose, graphql, mongodb-query, mean-stack

for my MEAN stack project I have to store a Date object in MongoDB for the start and end of a booking. the Date goes in just fine, in my collection it's show as:

```
booking_start: 2022-12-16T00:00:00.000+00:00

booking_end:  2022-12-29T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

but when i query my collection for all entries the Dates come out as strings  of numbers like this

```
                "booking_start": "1671148800000",
                "booking_end": "1672272000000"
```

what is going on here? I'll admit I'm new to working with Dates in Mongo but why is happening? I am using Graphql for my queries, but i don't think that the problem. is there a special way to query a Date?

here is my code and queries

resolver

```
        getuserbooking: async ()=>{
            const userListinglist = userbooking.find({})
            return userListinglist
        }
```

it's schema

```
type Query {
       
        getuserbooking:[userbooking]        
        
    }
```

and it's mongoose model

```
    booking_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required:[true,"Please enter booking date"],
    },
    booking_start:{
        type: Date,
        required:[true,"Please enter booking start"],
    },
    booking_end:{
        type: Date,
        required:[true,"Please enter booking end"]
```

Please any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: as this is my first question asked on the site please feel free to let me know if i need to include more information

Answer (score 0):

okay i figured out what went wrong, the numbers i kept getting back was a timestamp. i had to convert the timestamp into a Date so it could be displayed in the front end properly. if anyone else is having trouble with this here: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-convert-milliseconds-to-date
hint: if your timestamp is a string use parseInt()